# Planetary gears slip transmission

Tags: shimano, gears

I have Shimano gears and recently it starts slipping transmission under a pressure. That is pretty annoying and painful sometimes especially when you go uphill or accelerating on the traffic light.

I use the bike for already 6.5 years. Is it fixable or I have to change gears?

I didn't do much service, I think I oiled it 3 years ago.

Comment: So is it a internally geared hub such as the Alfine series?

Comment: Have you changed your chain/cogs in those 6.5 years?

Comment: Have you ever serviced the hub? Done an oil change every 5000 km or every year?

Comment: It's unclear what bike you have.  Is it an internally geared hub, or a bike with derailleurs?  What is the model?

Comment: Planetary gears = internally geared hub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going out on a limb but if you only maintained your internally-geared hub just once, three years ago, then its probably excessively worn due to poor maintenance.  Also the oil is likely carrying metal flakes which are doing continuous damage to the gears.

IGH are **low** maintenance but not zero-maintenance.

An oil change right now might be enough to bring it back but excessive wear will likely have shortened its overall life.  Depending on wear, you might benefit from a new 1/8" chain and new cog too.

If you can't or won't do maintenance yourself, then simply book it into the local bike shop for work annually and pay for someone else to do it.